# Common RoutePrefix in ASP.NET Core 7

Tags: routes, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working with ASP.NET Core 7.0. I have several controllers defining in this way:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/module/myController")]
public class MyControllerController :
```

Endpoints templates:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("create")]
    public IActionResult Create[FromBody] ....)
```

I would like to unify the place where this `api/module` part is configured so I can add/remove those segments depending on the implementation but not the rest.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://code-maze.com/aspnetcore-add-global-route-prefix/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Dimitris Maragkos!

I have successfully implemented your suggestion: https://code-maze.com/aspnetcore-add-global-route-prefix/